# Is it possible to add custom actions on the Users list view in Setup?

Tags: user-management

I created a custom flow for creating new users and assigning permission sets; I would like to either replace the standard New User button, or add a custom button of my own to launch the flow.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've searched online but not found any helpful info. I see the User object allows you to create custom buttons, but they don't show up on this page even when added to the list view layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.defining_custom_links.htm&type=5), Custom buttons aren’t available on the User object or custom home pages.